# Can't automate click in browser in one step

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to use this snipped of code in the "inspection console" on my browser to automate clicking items on a page.

When I paste the first two lines of JavaScript, press enter, and then paste the 3rd line, it works.

BUT if I paste the whole snippet at once I get an error saying: **VM107:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at :3:59**

The problem is I need this to be inside of a loop so I can't constantly paste parts of code for a big list...

```js
document.getElementById('browser-search-input').value = 'test';
getitems('all');
document.getElementById("result-documents").firstChild.click();
```

I'm not a web programmer, I just want to work efficient and i'm trying to make the best of the code I already came up with after lots of trail and error.

Comment: Need to check if there is a firstChild before trying to click on it. If it is null it means it doesn't exist (parent has no children)

Comment: but how does that explain that the 3rd code rule works if i paste-enter it afterwards?
shouldn't that be the same as running the whole snippet at once?

Comment: Depends when you run it and if any elements are added using javascript after you run it

Comment: okay, i run it when the page is loaded, i'm not sure how to determine if the elements are added with JavaScript. Do you perhaps know a way to run this code successfully at once even if the elements are not added using JavaScript after I run it?

Comment: You may need to check on an interval if they exist of use Mutation Observer API

Comment: i tried a while loop until the result is not "null".. freezes my browser haha
would you be so kind to give me a code example for the Mutation Observer API?

Comment: A while loop is bad approach. Try using `setInterval()`